# django LOGGING - How to change filter attribute name by format

Tags: django, logging

I have the following settings:

```
LOGGING = {
'version': 1,
'disable_existing_loggers': True,
'filters': {
    'require_debug_false': {
        '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'
    },
    'some_id': {
                '()': 'my.special.filter'
    },
},
'formatters': {
    'json': {
        '()': 'my.special.formatter',
        'format': '%(thread)d\t%(message)s'
    },
...
```

the filter add "some_id" to the log so the output looks like this:

```
{"thread": 140155333515008, "message": "some log msg", "some_id": "123456"}
```

I want to modify the additional attribute "some_id", so the output would look like this:

```
{"thread": 140155333515008, "message": "some log msg", "some-id": "123456"}
```

[I saw that it can be done with CustomAdapter](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#context-info) but I have a lot of "logger = logging.getLogger(...)" so I cant use this.

How can i change the output attribute name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for now, the solution is as following:

```
class my.special.formatter(JsonFormatter):
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(my.special.formatter, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

def format(self, record):
    if hasattr(record, 'some_id'):
        record.__setattr__('some-id', record.some_id)
        record.__delattr__('some_id')

    return super(my.special.formatter, self).format(record)
```

but its not ideal...